# Spyder 5 (Standalone) - Does not Start

Tags: python, windows-10, ide, spyder

Pretty newbe in Python programming and completely with Spyder IDE, am I trying to install the software on windows 10 64 but I cannot start it.

It crashes at launch when the splashscreen shows "Loading toolbars"
I tried to start the software through the terminal using: `python -m spyder.app.start`

but I get the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\anAnnoyingPerson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 2132, in create_window
    main.setup()
  File "C:\Users\anAnnoyingPerson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 903, in setup
    plugin_instance = plugin_class(self, configuration=CONF)
  File "C:\Users\anAnnoyingPerson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\preferences\plugin.py", line 58, in __init__
    super().__init__(parent, configuration)
  File "C:\Users\anAnnoyingPerson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\spyder\api\plugins.py", line 838, in __init__
    container.setup()
  File "C:\Users\anAnnoyingPerson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\preferences\widgets\container.py", line 107, in setup
    icon=self.create_icon('configure'),
  File "C:\Users\anAnnoyingPerson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\spyder\api\widgets\mixins.py", line 587, in create_icon
    return ima.icon(name)
  File "C:\Users\anAnnoyingPerson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\icon_manager.py", line 375, in icon
    directory=self._resource['directory'])
  File "C:\Users\anAnnoyingPerson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\qtawesome\__init__.py", line 201, in load_font
    return _instance().load_font(prefix, ttf_filename, charmap_filename, directory)
  File "C:\Users\anAnnoyingPerson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\qtawesome\__init__.py", line 76, in _instance
    ('mdi', 'materialdesignicons-webfont.ttf',
  File "C:\Users\anAnnoyingPerson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\qtawesome\iconic_font.py", line 214, in __init__
    self.load_font(*fargs)
  File "C:\Users\anAnnoyingPerson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\qtawesome\iconic_font.py", line 270, in load_font
    os.path.join(directory, ttf_filename)))
qtawesome.iconic_font.FontError: Font at 'C:\Users\anAnnoyingPerson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\qtawesome\fonts\fontawesome4.7-webfont.ttf' appears to be empty. If you are on Windows 10, please read https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3053676 to know how to prevent Windows from blocking the fonts that come with QtAwesome.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\anAnnoyingPerson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\anAnnoyingPerson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\anAnnoyingPerson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 244, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\anAnnoyingPerson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 226, in main
    mainwindow.main(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\anAnnoyingPerson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 2282, in main
    mainwindow = create_window(app, splash, options, args)
  File "C:\Users\anAnnoyingPerson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 2134, in create_window
    if main.console is not None:
  File "C:\Users\anAnnoyingPerson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 1156, in __getattr__
    return self.get_plugin(self._INTERNAL_PLUGINS_MAPPING[attr])
  File "C:\Users\anAnnoyingPerson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 170, in get_plugin
    'Plugin "{}" not found!'.format(plugin_name))
spyder.api.exceptions.SpyderAPIError: Plugin "internal_console" not found!
```

I tried to reinstall Spyder, upgrade the linked plugins, do it admin, local, through pip, through the exe installer (again) tried also the `spyder --reset` function. it did not work.

I tried to solve the qtawesome issue too but:

- I cannot install the TTF or OFT file (get the message "Is not a valid font file")
- I Tried to do the solutions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-client/shell-experience/feature-to-block-untrusted-fonts. But even in Reg, Python is not listed inside..

Could someone help me to find a solution?

Thank you and have a great day.

Comment: You didn't managed to set the QtAwesome font files as trusted, right? Maybe as a workaround you could change the theme preference to use the Spyder 2 icon theme. For that you need to find the `spyder.ini` file where Spyder preferences are stored (should be at `C:\Users\<your user>\.spyder-py3\config`) and change the entry `icon_theme = spyder 3` to be `icon_theme = spyder 2`

Comment: Hi, what to mean to specifiy QTAwesome files as trusted? I tried to make them trusted using the solution given in the link in my question. But I cannot install them as they are not recognized as Font file. And in Regedit I could not find Python in the list. 
Is there another method to make the file as trusted?

In parallel I will try you solution with the spyder 2.

EDIT: It worked with spyder 2! So indeed the font is the problem

Comment: Glad the workaround worked. Regarding the font installation, you went to the QtAwesome font folder (`C:\Users\anAnnoyingPerson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\qtawesome\fonts\`)` and tried to install the `fontawesome4.7-webfont.ttf` file by doing right click on it and selecting `Install`? Do you have rights to install fonts in the machine you are using?

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thanks for your time. TO answer your question: Yes I have admin right on my computer. I also already tried to install the font like you recommended and other method (open the font folder and past it here, double click on the to at least see the font in the table, try with OTF or TTF) nothing worked. (My) Windows 10 does not recognize this file as a font file..

Comment: I see, for me right clicking the files will show me the install option and even a install option for all the users. Maybe in your case some user policy is in place preventing the OS even trying to give access to this kind of files. Did you try what the Microsoft link says about copying them?:

_On each computer that has the app installed, right-click the font name, and then click Install.

The font should automatically install into your %windir%/Fonts directory.` **If it does not, you have to manually copy the font files into the Fonts directory and run the installation from there.**_

Comment: I tried also the copy/paste or drag and drop as mentioned. Unfortunately it did not worked. Still have the "non Valid font file" error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many thanks to Daniel Althviz. It was indeed the font which was blocking the Gui generation.

Using the `icon_theme = spyder 2` in `C:\Users\<your user>\.spyder-py3\config` the problem was solved.

Comment: didnt solve mine

Comment: Changing icon_theme worked for me, but seems kinda braindead.   Instead of throwing a random FileNotFoundError it might be nice if the startup code would at least fail gracefully.   I mean, the kindness of strangers is great, but it would be better if not necessary in the first place